# Tua vs Sua - what are the differences?

Tags: word-usage, difference, adjectives

I am studying Italian on Duolingo, and I was asked to translate

> "The pink shirt is hers"

I have translated the sentence to

> La camicia rosa e la **tua**

but was corrected to

> La camicia rosa e la **sua**

I can't seem to distinguish between the two - when should I use one and not the other ?

Comment: It seems that you should study Italian possessive adjectives. Notice also that the third person singular of present indicative of the verb "essere" is "è" with an accent.

Comment: Once in a while someone arrives here from Duolingo with a clueless question. I trust the goodwill of these people; I trust a little less the effectiveness of Duolingo.

Answer (score 4):

In this case the shirt belongs to a person which is neither the speaker nor the person listening, but a third different person.

So you translate "la camicia rosa è la **sua**".

If you say "la camicia rosa è la **tua**" you would  translate "the  pink shirt is ***yours***", meaning that it belongs to the person you're talking to.

Have a look to [Italian possessive adjectives](http://www.italianlanguageguide.com/grammar/possessive-adjective.asp) if you want to learn more.

Answer (score 4):

The possessive adjectives in Italian are

> first person singular: mio/mia/miei/mie
>   second personal singular: tuo/tua/tuoi/tue
>   third person singular: suo/sua/suoi/sue
>   first person plural: nostro/nostra/nostri/nostre
>   second person plural: vostro/vostra/vostri/vostre
>   third person plural: loro

The list is in the usual order, with the full declension for the masculine and feminine form, singular and plural. Note that the plural third person form is invariable.

These adjectives are also used as pronouns, so they correspond to the English forms

> first person singular: my/mine
>   second person singular: your/yours (archaic: thy/thine)
>   third person singular: his/her/hers/its
>   first person plural: our/ours
>   second person plural: your/yours
>   third person plural: their/theirs

The difference between Italian and English is that in Italian the adjective agrees with the gender of the possessed thing, whilst in English it agrees with the gender of the possessor.

Since the English pronoun is in the third person singular, the same should be used in Italian:

> La camicia rosa è sua

The same sentence would translate the English *The pink shirt is his*.

The suggested translation by Duolingo is disputable: in this case the article in front of the possessive is not at all required: it *can* be used for special emphasis in standard Italian; however, some varieties of Italian use it regularly and it may sound strange to people like me.

---

By the way, *la camicia rosa e la tua* means a very different thing from *la camicia rosa è (la) tua*. The latter is *the pink shirt is yours*, the former means *the pink shirt and yours*. Never forget the accent on *è* (present tense, third person singular of *essere*).